# What is the procedure to reset admin windows 7 password on boot camp mac pro?

Tags: windows-7

How can I reset the administrator password on apple bootcamp since it doesn't have a bios? It uses EFI.

Comment: There are dozens of tools that can reset a windows users password that support EFI what tools have you tried?

Comment: i tried this software. http://www.windowspasswordsrecovery.com/ but it didn't work at all. hd not detected

Comment: Can't you insert the installation disk and hold OPTION while your Mac is booting? If you click on the DVD and reset the password by following [these instructions](http://www.top-password.com/blog/reset-windows-7-password-with-windows-installation-cd/) (it's just a guess, might work).

Comment: looks like i was able to boot into ubuntu and rename the utilman.exe to cmd.exe trick and run netuser. thanks!